# Can we just keep particular tags inside a parent tag and delete all other tags in xslt1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Let's say i have data like below:

```
<caption>
 <p> some data </p>
 <b> bold data </b>
 <i> italic data </i>
 <a href=""> link data </a> 
 <u> underline data </u>
 <ul>
   <li>ul list data</li>
 </ul>  
 <ol>
   <li>ol list data</li>
 </ol>
</caption>
```

I want output as:

```
<caption>
 some data 
 <b> bold data </b>
 <i> italic data </i>
 <a href=""> link data </a> 
 <u> underline data </u>
  ul list data
  ol list data
</caption>
```

I want to delete all tags inside caption tag except bold italic underine and anchor tag. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the identity template where you want to retain the tags:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and a variant that drops the tags in other cases:

```
<xsl:template match="p|ul|ol|li">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: appreciate your suggestion but i got the other way to do this

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but I think you will find that this is how most experienced XSLT users would do it. But if you have another answer to your own question, please post it, so other people coming here can compare.